# IF Else Math Issues

Tags: r

I have some data that is a bit off.  In short, my columns look like this...

```
Percent
20
NA
NA
.002
.3
```

Now, I wrote the following code:

```
x <- Percent
data <- if(x > 1){
x/100
} else {x*1}
```

The returned math has everything (but NA) being divided by 100.  As 0.2 is less than 1, I am a bit confused as I just want it multiplied by 1 so it stays the same.  I feel like it isn't reading or understanding the else function. I am pretty new at these so I apologize in advance for being such a noob and am grateful for your help.

Comment: Try just x instead of x*1. Alternatively: `library(dplyr) data <- data %>% mutate(Percent = if_else(Percent > 1, Percent * 100, Percent))`.

Comment: @dcsuka This has nothing to do with `x*1` or `x`. The issue is that the condition in `if` statement cannot have length > 1. In this case you should use `ifelse()` because of its vectorization. I.e. `ifelse(x > 1, x/100, x)`. Btw, there is no need to load `dplyr` to explain this issue.

Comment: Oh, I simply meant that the *1 is redundant.

Comment: More typing, but you don't even need `ifelse`: `cond <- x > 1 & !is.na(x); x[cond] <- x[cond]/100`.

Comment: Hey Everyone!  I have this code: x <- data_stacked$Percent
data_stacked <- x %>% mutate(x = if_else(x > 1, x / 100, Percent))
head(data_stacked)
beep()  and I am still not getting anything to mutate.

Comment: I also went to the ifelse option and while I can pull the data.frame into its own section and run the command, within the data.frame I want (aka main data table), I don't get any answers.  Do I need to have a function? Like function(x) then define x as the column I want to mutate?  So my function X would be any of ya'lls answers (ifelse for example), then I'd run the function on the column?

Comment: I got it!  I had to pipe the df in.  Thanks everyone!